# Excel 2007 does not allow reference to xlam from xlsm

Tags: excel, excel-addins, vba

I am running Excel 2007 under Windows 7 Pro.

- I have two add-ins which I have saved as .xla, i.e. as "Excel 97-2003 Add-in".
- One is a "Master" add-in, which refers to the other, the "Slave" (through Tools > References)

In VBA, I am able to make a reference the Master add-in from another spreadsheet saved as .xlsm format. It appears to work fine.

Problem:

- I change the format of the add-ins from .xla to .xlam (this is non-trivial, involving saving as .xlsm format in between)
- I change the reference in the Master .xlam to point to the new Slave .xlam. That works fine, and can be tested.
- But when I try to reference the master from the .xlsm spreadsheet, then I get the message "Can't add a reference to the specified file".
- If I try again I get a message that just says "400".

Can anyone suggest why it is not possible to add a reference to .xlam from the .xlsm? The code is identical across the two add-in formats. There is no problem in referencing from the Master .xlam to the Slave .xlam . The problem only appears when trying to reference the Master .xlam from the .xlsm spreadsheet.

Both add-ins also refer to other libraries:

- Visual Basic for Applications
- Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Scripting Runtime
- Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library

I also tried saving the Master as .xslm, and referencing that. It works fine but of course the worksheets of the Master add-in are then visible, which I wanted to avoid.

Thanks for your help.